# How to get lines following a regex match in groovy?

Tags: regex, groovy

I should get the lines following the string that matches the line "abcd efgh".
Can someone help to write a groovy regex for this?

For eg in text:

```
dafdsdf
abcd efgh
hello
hi
new
```

Result should be :

```
hello
hi
new
```

Help please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need a regular expression...

```
def text = '''dafdsdf
abcd efgh
hello
hi
new'''

text.split('\n')                      // Split into lines
    .dropWhile { it != 'abcd efgh' }  // Drop all lines before the text
    .drop(1)                          // Drop the line with the text
    .each { println it }              // Print the rest out
```

Comment: Does this dropwhile function works with regex match? @tim_yates

Comment: It can do, it just wants a boolean...  `.dropWhile { !(it ==~ /abcd.+/) }` will drop until the line has `abcd` and then any other chars

Comment: Awesome Tim. It works. can we include a condition inside this each to print until some limit? @tim_yates

Comment: I don't understand, can you explain?

Comment: can we restrict the print inside each to print only until certain line. Say it should print only until 'hi' in the above example. @tim_yates

Comment: Add a `.takeWhile { it != 'end condition' }` after the `.drop(1)` and before the `.each`

Comment: Thanks lot Tim @tim_yates